# Rxjs - Is there a static creation operator behaves like 'switchMap'?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, reactivex

## Problem

`mergeMap` has a static counterpart as `merge`

`concatMap` has a static counterpart as `concat`

So is there something like a static `switch`?

## Motivation

It might be useful if I want to have a `Subject`-like behavior with an async-ly loaded initial value (like a network request). If the user manually set its value before the async results arrives, then we cancel the initialization process.

So there is no data race (if we use `merge` or `source.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => subj.next(val))`) or blocking (if we use `concat`).

```
let setValue$ = new Subject();
let getValue$ = switchStatic(
  getInitialValue().pipe(take(1)),
  setValue
)
```

If none, how do we implement this behavior?

Comment: I think you're looking for `race`: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/race

Comment: No, if one observable emits a value first, then `race` will completely ignore any other observables. `switch` will eventually stick with the last observable.

Comment: Ah, I see. You want the values emitted by th subject to be emitted whether or not the initialization observable has emitted. Something like this should work, if I'm not mistaken: `concat(getInitialValue().pipe(takeUntil(setValue$)), setValue$)`

Comment: This is truly marvelous! Thank you!